# Ordering Items In A List<T> Collection

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating my own user control that can display n amount of images.

Here is the code for it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebServiceScanner
{
    public partial class imageList : UserControl
    {
        public imageList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<Image> Images { get; set; }

        public void AddImage(Image image)
        {
            Images.Add(image);
        }

        public void RemoveImage(Image image)
        {
            Images.Remove(image);
        }

        public void MoveImageLeft(int index)
        {
            Image tmpImage = Images[index];
            Images[index] = Images[index - 1];
            Images[index - 1] = tmpImage;
        }
    }
}
```

I have two questions. Will the .Remove() method, correctly remove the image I want with my current implementation?

Also, I need a way to move an Image to the left by one position. Any suggestions?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you need to add some checks on the index passed in, your solution should do the trick (for both questions) - is there something you're not happy with?

Comment: I don't know what's being asked here: "does the code I posted work?" Try it and find out. Let us know if it doesn't, and *then* maybe we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Remove" should work - AFAIK, the CLR will do a hash to compare image objects in the list, and if it sees matching hashes, it will remove the appropriate object.

To move an image left, you could use `RemoveAt` and `Insert`.